# Digital signature with SHA1 and DSA

Tags: java, digital-signature, sha1

I have a Base64 string that I have to sign with SHA1withRSA or SHA1withDSA.

Can anybody give me a few hint about how to get this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SHA1 and RSA with java.security.Signature vs. MessageDigest and Cipher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521101/using-sha1-and-rsa-with-java-security-signature-vs-messagedigest-and-cipher)

Answer (score 0):

Googling `java sign sha1withdsa` finds http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch04_13.htm as the 10th result.

Answer (score 0):

[Keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/) uses SHA1 and DSA for its signing. That's probably a quite easy solution to use.