# iOS verify digital signature

Tags: ios, cryptography, digital-signature

In my application, I have a public key (represented as string), plain message and digital signature, represented as base64 encoded string, hashed with SHA256 and encrypted with RSA).
Now, I need to verify digital signature. I was trying to do as follows:

1. create `SecKeyRef` from `NSString` (taken from [here](http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/))
2. create SHA256 digest from original message
3. verify signature using `SecKeyRawVerify` function

(I am trying to avoid using OpenSSL function)

Additionally, my digital signature was created using Java's SHA256withRSA method. I was reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521101/using-sha1-and-rsa-with-java-security-signature-vs-messagedigest-and-cipher) that SHA256WithRSA appends algorithm identifier with the actual hash. Now, I am not sure whether or not I need to append it to the hash.

Anyway, in both cases I get error -50, which according to Apple's documentations means *One
or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.*

Here is my code:

```
-(BOOL) verifySignature:(NSString*) rawData andKey:(NSString*) key andSignature:(NSString*)signature {

    NSData* originalData = [rawData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *signatureData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:signature];

    SecKeyRef publicKey = [self generatePublicKey:key];

    uint8_t sha2HashDigest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256([originalData bytes], [originalData length], sha2HashDigest);

    //DO I NEED THIS?
    NSString *algIdentifier = @"1.3.14.3.2.26";
    NSData *algData = [algIdentifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData* d_hash = [NSData dataWithBytes:sha2HashDigest length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    NSMutableData *concatenatedData = [NSMutableData data];
    [concatenatedData appendData:algData];
    [concatenatedData appendData:d_hash];

    OSStatus verficationResult =  SecKeyRawVerify (publicKey,
                     kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256,
                     (const uint8_t *)[d_hash bytes],
                     (size_t)[d_hash length],
                     (const uint8_t *)[signatureData bytes],
                     (size_t)[signatureData length]
                     );


    CFRelease(publicKey);

    if (verficationResult == errSecSuccess){
        NSLog(@"Verified");
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;

}

- (SecKeyRef)generatePublicKey:(NSString *)key
{

    // This will be base64 encoded, decode it.
    NSData *d_key = [NSData dataFromBase64String:key];
    d_key = [self stripPublicKeyHeader:d_key];
    if (d_key == nil) return(nil);

    NSData *d_tag = [NSData dataWithBytes:[@"pubKey" UTF8String] length:[@"pubKey" length]];

    NSMutableDictionary *publicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [publicKey setObject:(id) kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
    [publicKey setObject:(id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [publicKey setObject:d_tag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)publicKey);

    CFTypeRef persistKey = nil;

    // Add persistent version of the key to system keychain
    [publicKey setObject:d_key forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
    [publicKey setObject:(id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic forKey:(id)
     kSecAttrKeyClass];
    [publicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)
     kSecReturnPersistentRef];

    OSStatus secStatus = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)publicKey, &persistKey);
    if (persistKey != nil) CFRelease(persistKey);

    if ((secStatus != noErr) && (secStatus != errSecDuplicateItem)) {
        [publicKey release];
        return(nil);
    }

    // Now fetch the SecKeyRef version of the key
    SecKeyRef keyRef = nil;

    [publicKey removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
    [publicKey removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];
    [publicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnRef
     ];

    [publicKey setObject:(id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    secStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)publicKey,
                                    (CFTypeRef *)&keyRef);

    [publicKey release];
    return keyRef;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this answer is a little late but I had the same problem.

It turns out that Java handles the hashing for you, but iOS does not.

So if you have a plaintext called `plainText` you might generate a signature on it in Java doing this:

```
public static byte[] sign(PrivateKey key, byte[] plainText) {
    try {
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initSign(key);
        signature.update(plainText);
        return signature.sign();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But then to verify it in iOS you need to manually take a hash of the plaintext like so:

```
+ (BOOL)verifySignature:(uint8_t*)signature signatureLen:(size_t)sLen
            withPlainText:(uint8_t*)plainText plainTextLen:(size_t)pLen
            andKey:(SecKeyRef)key {
    uint8_t hash[32];
    CC_SHA256(plainText, pLen, hash);
    OSStatus returnCode = SecKeyRawVerify(key,
                                          kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256,
                                          hash,
                                          32,
                                          signature,
                                          sLen);
    return returnCode == 0;
}
```

In the above method, `signature` is the bytes generated by the Java method.

Of course, you may not want to hardcode parameters such as the the hash function used (and length of hash).

Comment: Before the call to SecKeyRawVerify, you need to preprend the algorithm identifier to your "hash" array obtained with CC_SHA256

Comment: Hmm I don't see where it states that in the documentation. It says for that argument: "the data over which [signature] is being verified, typically the digest of the actual data" and so I passed the digest of the actual data (a SHA256 hash). Could you elaborate? What format is that specifically?

Comment: Did just passing the data worked for you? I had to prepend an algorithm identifier to the actual hashed data.  id-sha256: 30 0b 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01

Comment: Thanks, @user3100783! Knowing this behavior of the Java Signature class is really helpful!