# Verifying signature generated with Java using native Security framework on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, hash, rsa, digital-signature

I have a digital signature generated by the server with a private key using RSA algorithm combined with SHA1 hashing algorithm, and I want to verify it with a public key on an iOS device using its native libraries. Through searching for this question I figured that I have to follow these steps:

1. Get the public key from the server.
2. Strip the extra header that is packaged with it.
3. Hash the data that we want to verify using SHA1 algorithm.
4. Pass the the hashed data along with the public key, the right padding algorithm option,  and the signature data to the method "SecKeyRawVerify".

The problem is that I always get the error -9809, I checked many questions here but none of the solutions worked for me, and I think that I covered everything the right way.

Here is my current code:

First "CryptographyFactory" is the class I'm using to integrate all the process

```
+ (BOOL)verifyData:(NSData *)dataToVerify withPublickeyAsBytes:(NSData *)publicKey andSignedData:(NSData *)signedData
{
    SecKeyRef key = [CryptographyFactory getRSAPublicKeyFromKeyAsData:publicKey];
    return [CryptographyFactory verifyData:dataToVerify withPublickey:key andSignedData:signedData];
}
```

The following two methods are to extract the public key from the bytes I got from the server including stripping the header from it, these methods were basically taken from [here](http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/) with a little twist

```
+ (SecKeyRef)getRSAPublicKeyFromKeyAsData:(NSData *)publicKeyAsData
{
    publicKeyAsData = [CryptographyFactory stripPublicKeyHeader:publicKeyAsData];

    if (publicKeyAsData == nil) {
        return NO;
    }

    NSString * tag = @"com.sometag.someothertag";
    NSData *d_tag = [NSData dataWithBytes:[tag UTF8String] length:[tag length]];

    // Delete any old lingering key with the same tag
    NSMutableDictionary *publicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [publicKey setObject:(id) CFBridgingRelease(kSecClassKey) forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecClass)];
    [publicKey setObject:(id) CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA) forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrKeyType)];
    [publicKey setObject:d_tag forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrApplicationTag)];
    SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)CFBridgingRetain(publicKey));

    CFTypeRef persistKey = nil;

    // Add persistent version of the key to system keychain
    [publicKey setObject:publicKeyAsData forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecValueData)];
    [publicKey setObject:(id) CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrKeyClassPublic) forKey:(id)
    CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrKeyClass)];
    [publicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)
     CFBridgingRelease(kSecReturnPersistentRef)];

    OSStatus secStatus = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)CFBridgingRetain(publicKey), &persistKey);
    if (persistKey != nil) CFRelease(persistKey);

    if ((secStatus != noErr) && (secStatus != errSecDuplicateItem)) {
        return nil;
    }

    //Now fetch the SecKeyRef version of the key
    SecKeyRef keyRef = nil;

    [publicKey removeObjectForKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecValueData)];
    [publicKey removeObjectForKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecReturnPersistentRef)];
    [publicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecReturnRef)];
    [publicKey setObject:(id) CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA) forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrKeyType)];
    secStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)CFBridgingRetain(publicKey),
                                (CFTypeRef *)&keyRef);


    if (keyRef == nil) return nil;

    return(keyRef);
}

+ (NSData *)stripPublicKeyHeader:(NSData *)d_key
{
    // Skip ASN.1 public key header
    if (d_key == nil) return(nil);

    unsigned int len = [d_key length];
    if (!len) return(nil);

    unsigned char *c_key = (unsigned char *)[d_key bytes];
    unsigned int  idx    = 0;

    if (c_key[idx++] != 0x30) return(nil);

    if (c_key[idx] > 0x80) idx += c_key[idx] - 0x80 + 1;
    else idx++;

    // PKCS #1 rsaEncryption szOID_RSA_RSA
    static unsigned char seqiod[] =
    { 0x30,   0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01,
    0x01, 0x05, 0x00 };
    if (memcmp(&c_key[idx], seqiod, 15)) return(nil);

    idx += 15;

    if (c_key[idx++] != 0x03) return(nil);

    if (c_key[idx] > 0x80) idx += c_key[idx] - 0x80 + 1;
    else idx++;

    if (c_key[idx++] != '\0') return(nil);

    // Now make a new NSData from this buffer
    return([NSData dataWithBytes:&c_key[idx] length:len - idx]);
}
```

Now these are the methods that actually try to verify the signature:

```
+ (BOOL)verifyData:(NSData *)dataToVerify withPublickey:(SecKeyRef)publicKey andSignedData:(NSData *)signedData
{

    if (dataToVerify == nil || signedData == nil || dataToVerify.length == 0 || signedData.length == 0) {
    return NO;
    }



    BOOL valid = NO;

    uint8_t * signature = (uint8_t *)[signedData bytes];
    size_t signatureLen = [signedData length];
    uint8_t * plainText = (uint8_t *)[dataToVerify bytes];
    size_t plainTextLen = [dataToVerify length];

    valid = [CryptographyFactory verifySignature:signature signatureLen:signatureLen withPlainText:plainText plainTextLen:plainTextLen andKey:publicKey];

    return valid;
}


+ (BOOL)verifySignature:(uint8_t*)signature signatureLen:(size_t)sLen
          withPlainText:(uint8_t*)plainText plainTextLen:(size_t)pLen
                 andKey:(SecKeyRef)key {
    uint8_t hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA1(plainText, pLen, hash);

    OSStatus returnCode = SecKeyRawVerify(key,
                                      kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1,
                                      (const uint8_t *)hash,
                                      CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH,
                                      signature,
                                      sLen);
    return returnCode == 0;
}
```

The last two methods are inspired by the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022526/ios-verify-digital-signature).

Actually the guys over there mentioned a solution by adding some prefixes to the hashed data but that was not really clear.

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Sorry to post some issue that was discussed so many times before.

Comment: I am also facing the same error for quite sometime now. Were you able to fix this error?

Comment: Actually it turned out that the data passed to the methods weren't really correct and the reason was the passed bytes were converted from a string and the string was built with small letters not capital ones, I know that was really a stupid error from my side. Please try to use the code I provided and should work for you.