# Verify a SHA-256 signature with public key from modulus and exponent

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, sha256

I have been wrapping my head around this problem for some time now. I am to implement a signature check, which is already implemented using c# but we need to implement it on iOS also.

The c# code looks like this.

```
var signedData = version + "#" + string.Join("#", deltas.Select(s => s.Key + "=" + s.Value));
var signature = Convert.FromBase64String(vertification);
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{ //TODO: Configuration 
rsa.FromXmlString("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>a long text here</Modulus><Exponent>a small text here</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>"); 
var valid = rsa.VerifyData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signedData), new SHA256Managed(), signature); 
return valid; 
}
```

A little catch is that we can't use any cocoa pods or external libraries.

Comment: That's not a little catch! You need to implement the required `RSACrytoServiceProvider` functionality yourself. I suggest you get reflector and reverse engineer the `RSACrytoServiceProvider` class to convert to objective C.

Comment: Ok so now that i have tried without using any external libraries and given up. Do you know any solutions with libraries?

Comment: Try this SO question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022526/ios-verify-digital-signature ... i googled 'ios verify sha256'. Hope that helps ... certainly seems easier than implementing RSA algorithms yourself ;0)