# How to make "MessageDigest SHA-1 and Signature NONEwithRSA" equivalent to "Signature SHA1withRSA "

Tags: java, hash, rsa, keystore, sha

I am interested in applying a SHA-1 hash with RSA signature to some data, but I need to do it in two steps - apply hash first and then sign the data.  The Signature.sign() function appears to create a more complex (ASN.1?) data structure that is ultimately signed (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521101/using-sha1-and-rsa-with-java-security-signature-vs-messagedigest-and-cipher)). How can I make the two equivalent without using any external libraries like BouncyCastle?

Apply hash and sign in single step with Signature:

```
PrivateKey privatekey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
...
sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "SunMSCAPI");
sig.initSign(privatekey);
sig.update(data_to_sign);
byte[] bSignedData_CAPISHA1_CAPIRSA = sig.sign();
```

Apply hash via MessageDigest, then sign with Signature:

```
PrivateKey privatekey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
...
MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] data_to_sign = sha1.digest(bdataToSign);
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA", "SunMSCAPI");
sig.initSign(privatekey);
sig.update(data_to_sign);
byte[] bSignedData_JAVASHA1_CAPIRSA = sig.sign();
...
```

I am looking for the following equivalency:

```
bSignedData_JAVASHA1_CAPIRSA == bSignedData_CAPISHA1_CAPIRSA
```

My ultimate goal is to create the hash and then sign with a PKCS11 token, but I require the signed data to be the same format as legacy data for verification purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

1. The data to be signed needed to be formatted correctly in a
   DigestInfo DER-encoded byte array.  The Signature SHA1withRSA takes
   care of this for you, but if you want to accomplish it in a two-step
   process, you need to create your own DigestInfo.  I ended up copying
   a very minimal amount of ASN.1 classes from BouncyCastle into my
   project to accomplish this, despite my desire not to use a third
   party lib.
2. If you try to use the Cipher API to encrypt the DigestInfo, the
   PKCS1 padding will be random and not appropriate for a digital
   signature.  I needed static padding.
3. The Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA", "SunMSCAPI") rejects the
   DER-encoded DigestInfo format, and will return an error if you try
   to sign that data.  But, since I ultimately wanted to use the PKCS11
   API to generate the signature, I ended up signing the DER-encoded
   DigestInfo with the PKCS11 C_SignInit and C_Sign functions.

To summarize, what worked for me was:

1. generate the SHA-1 hash of the data to sign using the Java MessageDigest API
2. generated a DigestInfo DER-encoded ASN.1 object with the SHA-1 hash and SHA-1 OID embedded in the object.
3. signed the DigestInfo using the PKCS11 C_Sign function from a third party library.

The following links were most helpful in solving my problem:

[Oracle Forums: SHA1withRSA - how to do that in 2 steps?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1528715?start=0&tstart=0)

[StackOverflow: Using SHA1 and RSA with java.security.Signature vs. MessageDigest and Cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521101/using-sha1-and-rsa-with-java-security-signature-vs-messagedigest-and-cipher)

Answer (score 3):

emsworth's answer was when a great help for me when struggling with the same issue (but using SHA512). However it is still missing a hint which takes me a few more days to find out by myself.

There are different ways how the signature is constructed. For example when using RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (from RFC 5246, TLS 1.2) the DER-encoded DigestInfo is not obtained the usual way. For example if using BouncyCastle

```
DigestInfo digestInfo = new DigestInfo(new AlgorithmIdentifier(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha512), hash);
byte[] digestedHash = digestInfo.getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DER);
```

does not yield the expected results. RFC 3447 defines how to construct the DER encoding on page 42. For example in case of SHA-512 the DER encoding is as follows:

```
// code example includes MessageDigest for the sake of completeness
byte[] input = ... // the raw data
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
md.update(input);
byte[] hash = md.digest();

// Taken from RFC 3447, page 42 for SHA-512, create input for signing
byte[] modifierBytes = { 0x30, 0x51, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, (byte) 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x03, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x40 };
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos.write(modifierBytes);
baos2.write(hash);

// create signature
Signature s = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
s.initSign(MyTlsCredentials.THE_CLIENT_KEY);
s.update(baos.toByteArray());
byte[] signature = s.sign();

// add prefix as specified in RFC 3447, im my case it had always been the shown values
// but I have not understand the RFC completely in this point as the code seems to be
// contradictious to the interpretation of the byte values for the hash function from page 42.
ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos2.write(new byte[] { 1, 0 });
baos2.write(signature5);
```

Comment: Your answer is great. Thanks to you, I saved a lot of time looking for a solution (especially when looking for [this standart](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447#page-42)).
Your first attempt was so close to working:
`new DigestInfo(new AlgorithmIdentifier(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha512, DERNull.INSTANCE), digest).getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DER);`. Pay attention to `DERNull.INSTANCE` in `AlgorithmIdentifier` constructor args.

Comment: Alternative way to solve the problem (SUN JCE way): `DerOutputStream out = new DerOutputStream(); new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.SHA256_oid).encode(out); out.putOctetString(digest); DerValue result = new DerValue(DerValue.tag_Sequence, out.toByteArray()); return result.toByteArray();`

Answer (score 1):

Example of implementation according to the answers of other colleagues (might be useful for someone):

```
class SignatureTest {
    @Test
    void signAndVerify() throws Exception {
        byte[] message = "some text".getBytes();
        KeyPair keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA").generateKeyPair();

        byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(message);
        // or encodeToPKCS1BySunJCE() may be called
        byte[] pkcs1EncodedDigest = encodeToPKCS1ByBounceCastle(digest);

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
        signature.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
        signature.update(pkcs1EncodedDigest);
        byte[] digestSignature = signature.sign();

        signature.initVerify(keyPair.getPublic());
        signature.update(pkcs1EncodedDigest);
        assertTrue(signature.verify(digestSignature));
    }

    @Test
    void signDigestAndMessage() throws Exception {
        byte[] message = "some text".getBytes();
        KeyPair keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA").generateKeyPair();

        byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(message);
        // or encodeToPKCS1BySunJCE() may be called
        byte[] pkcs1EncodedDigest = encodeToPKCS1BySunJCE(digest);

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
        signature.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
        signature.update(pkcs1EncodedDigest);
        byte[] signedDigest = signature.sign();

        signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA");
        signature.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
        signature.update(message);
        byte[] signedMessage = signature.sign();

        assertEquals(signedDigest, signedMessage);
    }

    private byte[] encodeToPKCS1ByBounceCastle(byte[] digest) throws IOException {
        return new DigestInfo(new AlgorithmIdentifier(X509ObjectIdentifiers.id_SHA1, DERNull.INSTANCE), digest).getEncoded();
    }

    private byte[] encodeToPKCS1BySunJCE(byte[] digest) throws IOException {
        DerOutputStream out = new DerOutputStream();
        new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.SHA_oid).encode(out);
        out.putOctetString(digest);
        return new DerValue(DerValue.tag_Sequence, out.toByteArray()).toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is example for `SHA256withRSA`

```kotlin
@Test
fun signDigestAndMessageSHA256() {
    val message = "message"

    val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(payload.toByteArray())
    val encodedDigest: ByteArray = DigestInfo(AlgorithmIdentifier(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256, DERNull.INSTANCE), digest).encoded

    var signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA")
    signature.initSign(privateKey)
    signature.update(encodedDigest)
    val signedDigest = signature.sign()

    signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
    signature.initSign(privateKey)
    signature.update(payload.toByteArray())
    val signedMessage = signature.sign()

    Assert.assertEquals(signedDigest.joinToString(), signedMessage.joinToString())
}
```