# Java - How to generate Digital Signature without using java's ''Signature' library?

Tags: java, digital-signature

I have generated a public and a private key, but how do I sign a text document without using security.Signature library? The reason behind this is because our Professor stated that we should finish the task without using the build-in library

Comment: You could probably get a useful answer if you state what's specifically the reason you cannot or don't want to use that library.

Comment: Just curious, why can't you use it? The alternative will be implementing your own Signature class which is reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @GoranJovic Our cybersecurity Professor said we had to do this way, and I don't know where to start. I get the logic, but I don't know the code part..

Comment: @zengr ^ Then I think the task of my project is to reinvent the wheel. Our Professor asked to complete this task without using the library

Comment: I've said it [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066294/how-to-pass-biginteger-to-a-signature-function/29067446#comment46370163_29066294) and I say it again: So, you're asking someone to write an RSA signature implementation for you using BigInteger?

Comment: `BigInteger` has a method that you can use for the signature. Read your course materials or the Wikipedia article on RSA encryption to figure out which method to use and how to apply it. Also, be aware that a real RSA signature requires processing of the message before signing that is much more complicated and harder to implement than the signature operation itself. I don't know if that's part of your assignment, or if you are only expected to perform a naive and easily broken signature operation.

Answer (score 3):

I would look at [OpenJDK's Signature.java](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/security/Signature.java) to [understand](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step3.html) how its implemented. You need to focus on [what `.sign` does](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/DSA.java#L267)

If you are doing it for better understanding or academic purposes, I would follow [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187967&seqNum=5):

Step 1: Calculate the Message Digest (like SHA1 or even [MD5](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/oracle-jre-will-no-longer-trust-md5-signed-code-by-default) to start with)
Step 2: Calculate the Digital Signature (using public/private keys)

Comment: Thank you for the links. I scanned through the information and I think it will get the job done.